# Open and fill the text area in external link using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on module in PHP codeigniter where I want open the url http://searchpan.in/search-pan-details-pan-no/ from code and fill the value in PAN Numbers textarea dynamically. then user will manually click the submit button. I am using below code

```
$url = 'http://searchpan.in/search-pan-details-pan-no/';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
//curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $data;
```

It opens external link in browser. here I do not understand how I can assign value in textbox also how I can open link in new tab so current window of project will not disappear

Comment: Do you own this domain http://searchpan.in ? If not, you can't fill the value in PAN Numbers textarea dynamically. This just not possible at all.

Comment: You can send pan_numbers value by post method But that domain using Captcha.So if its your domain you can else sorry.

Comment: No I dont own it. We want to use it for verification purpose

Comment: Captcha will be inserted manually and submit will also manual. I just want to open this link in new tab. PAN will be inserted from my database